# Workouts don't become easier for me

Tags: workout-routines, workout, post-workout

I do an 8 minute workout every day with an application. My workout is a mix of different excercises (hindu push-ups, abdominal etc, 30 seconds each). before this I used to do easier work-outs. I've been doing this workout for more than a month regularly, but it doesn't become easier. I am stuck at "comfortable" level and my heart rate after workout is 110-130 bpm. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a general rule, the title of your question should be a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### *Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again but expecting different results*
>
> -Albert Einstein

When you do the same workout every day without changing your intensity, the reps, the sets, or overall time worked out, then you are going to plateau and that workout will no longer be enough to grow your muscles.

Increase your workout's intensity gradually over time (extra reps, add weight). Your body will adapt to the extra load by building more muscle. This muscle then helps support an even larger load: rinse and repeat.

As an aside, there are two problems with your workout that also contribute to poor muscle growth.

1. Daily workouts constantly stress your muscles but never gives them time to recover and grow bigger. Reduce to 3-4 days a week so they can properly recover and grow.
2. Eight minute workouts are not very intense, so you aren't able to do enough to really grow muscles in that time. Increase to 30 - 60 minutes so you can properly stress your muscles enough.

Answer (score 2):

Progress is easy, given  you  train regularly  and  have sufficient nutrition and rest.
For a beginner.
When you become advanced  and your achievements much  better  then  those of untrained people ,  you  need to  plan  cycles ,  as progress is possible only in specific part of the body or one skill at a time.

When you   become elite, ie world class sportsmen say   olimpics,  world championships,  national  level ....

At this stage your life is organized around one specific event (or say season).

Hardly  you are an  elite as in this case you  would have a coach/trainer.

So i  assume you  are  a novice.

In this case you  could try  to  change one of  3 variables:

You train too hard too often.
You do not  get  enough food to recover.
You do not  have enough sleep/rest to recover.

And there  is a possibility that your training  is not  intencive enough to shift  the homeostasis.  8 minutes  look  too short to  me ,  however   if you  do  Tabata protocol ,  for example  it is even  too much  ,  especially  every day.

Try  to think of it  and change one thing  at  a time ,  observe the  results  over 2 weeks  period  and then decide .

Comment: +1. You don't get better when you exercise, you get better when you are resting between exercises.